# Botnet simulator free for students or trial available

Tags: networking, simulation

I am looking for a tool to simulate the behaviour of a large botnet for research purposes. That is, I am searching a tool that can simulate hosts (bots, criminals that send commands to bots, victims and network infrastructure) on a network and their interaction.

A botnet is a network of infected computers who do the bidding of some criminal without knowledge or consent by their owners. They are used to send spam, host criminal content, etc. I want to do (legal!) research on these and therefore will need a simulator.

As creating such a tool is not the goal of my research I would like to limit my programming workload here, but I am in principle able to do some programming myself.

I want to simulate the behaviour of real world botnets, so I will also need to have nodes for general network infrastructure, such as DNS servers, but I do not need or want to fully emulate a TCP/IP network but just those infrastructure the bots interact with.

Now, I could do this using docker, but, if possible, I would like to have the simulation run faster than realtime. That is, the initial spreading of the network usually takes at least a few days. I would like to simulate it in minutes.

**Update:** I have Windows 7 and Ubuntu Linux and I don't care which of those the Simulator runs on. The simulator should be free for students, if possible. But I might probably also be able to get my university to spend 50$ on this if there is no free alternative.